# Get dates from day of week in a date range (start date, end date) and year in PowerQuery M

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I need to expand a list given the inputs: start date, end date and days of the week that something should happen. This needs to be done by using M in Power Query.

The date range can span multiple weeks, for example:

start date: 04/15/19

end date: 04/29/19

day of week: 1

I would expect to get 3 rows:

- 04/15/19

  04/22/19

  04/29/19

or encompass one week & day:

start date: 04/15/19

end date: 04/15/19

day of week: 1

I would expect to get 1 row:

- 04/15/19

I was using: [Get date from weeknumber, dayofweek and year PowerQuery M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159065/get-date-from-weeknumber-dayofweek-and-year-powerquery-m)
as a first step in understanding how to approach the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update your question to include whatever formula(s) you've tried so far?

Comment: If you have a date table that contains the entire date range you plan to work with, then you can write a function that simply returns a filtered subset of the date table based on start date, end date, and day of the week.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Also a valid approach. A date table would however require updating as time went on. start date and end date are not of a set range. The solution below does away with an intermediate date table. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I agree. Often you already have an existing date table though for other purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to list all dates in your chosen range, and filter to the chosen weekday:

```
(DateStart as date, DateEnd as date, DayOfWeek as number) =>
let
    #"Date List" = List.Dates(DateStart,Duration.Days(DateEnd-DateStart)+1,#duration(1,0,0,0)),
    #"Date Table" = Table.FromList(#"Date List", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Date"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Date Table",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Filtered Dates" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each (Date.DayOfWeek([Date], Day.Sunday) = DayOfWeek))
in
    #"Filtered Dates"
```

Invoked as a test:

```
let
    Source = fnListWeekdaysInRange(#date(2019, 4, 15), #date(2019, 4, 29), 1)
in
    Source
```

Which returns:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm - I modified it to read in from a "Dates to Expand" Table, use the columns (DateStart, DateEnd, DayOfWeek) as the function parameters and expand it with a Custom Function in a column.

Comment: "Day 7" is Sunday. When I have DayOfWeek = 7, there seems to be an issue. Returns an empty set. Did you run into this as well?

Comment: DayOfWeek enumerates from 0 to 6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-dayofweek

Comment: You could modify the comparison to `each (Date.DayOfWeek([Date], Day.Sunday) = Number.Mod(DayOfWeek,7))` if you need to pass Sunday as 7.

Comment: This was the perfect medicine. Before it was returning correct values for all days except day 7, now all days are filled. Excellent, thank you!