# How can I use DAX to calculate a date based on Week_Number, Year, and Day without a date column?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

In my data set I do not have date column . Columns I have are Week_Number (Number Format) , Year (Number Format) and Weekday (Text format).
When building my visuals I want the days to show in chronological (i.e Mon- Sun) order rather than in Alphabetical order.

**Sample data set**

[image]

Tried using DAX Formula : Keep on getting error : Token EOF error

```
New column =

var _st = date([Year],1,1)

var _st_week = _st  - weekday(_st ,2) +1 //Monday week

return

_st_week + (7 *[week no])
```

Comment: Maybe this helps as an inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159065/get-date-from-weeknumber-dayofweek-and-year-powerquery-m

Comment: EOF error is a PowerQuery parsing error. Are you using DAX code in PowerQuery? https://towardsdatascience.com/power-bi-m-vs-dax-vs-measures-4c77ae270790

Answer (score 0):

In your dataset, you don't have a column of dates. The columns you have are Week_Number (numeric format), Year (numeric format), and Weekday (text format).

When building your visualizations, you want the days to be displayed in chronological order (i.e. Monday through Sunday) rather than alphabetically.

It looks like you have a syntax error in your DAX formula. You can try to change it as follows :

```
New column =
VAR _st = DATE([Year], 1, 1)
VAR _st_week = _st - WEEKDAY(_st, 2) + 2 // Semaine du lundi
RETURN
_st_week + (7 * [Week_Number])
```